# Approximate first-order loss function with piecewise-linear functions in python

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, approximation, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to approximate the first-order loss function $$\mathbb{E}[max(d-y,0)]=\sigma \cdot (\phi(\frac{d-\mu}{\sigma})- \frac{d-\mu}{\sigma} \cdot (1- \Phi (\frac{d-\mu}{\sigma})),$$
where $d\in \mathbb{N}$ and $ y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

I need the approximation to solve an optimization problem. There is a discussion about lower & upper bounds in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300314000563 but I don't understand it.

Is there an easy way to approximate it with python, or in general to get a good and not to complex approximation of a non-linear function?

Comment: What exactly you don't understand in this paper ?

Comment: @KurtG. in 5.1 there is an upper limit for the number of functions with which the first order loss function should be approximated, but this is only valid for an interval from a to b, so what do i have to choose as a and b?

a would probably be 0, since we are only interested in positive production quantities, but what should b be?

Comment: The paper is not freely accessible. Best if you give context. What is the production quantity, etc. ? Does not sound like such a hard question. We need definitions, definitions and definitions.

Comment: @KurtG. the paper is only about the lower - and upper bound of an approximation for the first-order loss function in general, I'm trying to apply it to a production problem. I think it's a bit too much to post, because I don't understand it in general, that's why i'm trying to get more familiar with it first and find another paper if necessary. Anyway thanks for your time :)